# C: How do you call a function under a condition without using if-else?

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean, short-circuiting

In my intro to cs I'm told to write a program without using if\else statements or (a?b-c), and they gave us an int function something() -takes no value- that prints something as return. I want to use this function under some condition, but I can't figure out how I'm gonna call it without using if{}.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: You've tagged this "short-circuiting", so it seems that you already know (or have been given a hint about) one possible solution.

Comment: Are you allowed to use other control-flow structures? Loops, switch statements?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know what solution they had in mind, but since your function returns an `int`, you can use short-circuited evaluation:

```
int ignoreAnd = (oneNumber == anotherNumber) && someFunction();
int ignoreOr  = (oneNumber != anotherNumber) || someFunction();
```

In the first case the function would be called only when the condition is true; in the second case the function would be called only when the condition is false.

Comment: I think `int ignore = (yourCondition == somethingElse) && someFunction();` would be nicer.

Comment: @haccks Right, I was editing to add a second alternative, and added parentheses to "beautify" the example. Thank you!

Comment: This is likely the solution that "they" had in mind, given that the question is tagged "short-circuiting". There's probably some context that OP isn't telling us.

Comment: @interjay You are right, I did not notice the tag on the first reading, but since the tag is there, there must have been a hint of some sort given to the students about the expected solution.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why it works? to me it seems like you assign a value to a new variable depending on whether it's true or false, but I don't get why it actually calls the function?

Comment: @SaqquraChan Basically, `x = cond1 && cond2` works like `if (cond1) { if (cond2) { x = 1; } else { x = 0; } } else { x = 0; }` in that `cond2` is executed only if `cond1` is *true* first. Similarly, `y = cond1 || cond2` works like `if (cond1) { y = 1; } else if (cond2) { y = 1; } else { y = 0; }` in that `cond2` is executed only if `cond1` is *false* first. See [`&&` (logical AND)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical#Logical_AND) and [`||` (logical OR)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical#Logical_OR) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a switch statement instead of if else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loops while using break statement at the end to ensure it will be executed only once, instead of looping.
For loop:

```
for(;(a==b);)
{
    myFunc();
    break;// to make this loop execute only once.
}
```

While loop:

```
while(a==b){
    myFunc();
    break;
 }
```